# "DBF file can not be opened" error using shp2pgsql

Tags: shapefile, shp2pgsql

I am trying to import a shapefile using shp2pgsql. I wrote this command:

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 2154 -W "LATIN1" W:\IGN\BDPARCELLAIRE-RGF93-LB93-MAJ2013-V4\BDPV_1-2_SHP_LAMB93_D01\COMMUNE.shp CADASTRE.COMMUNE | psql -U postgres -d omexom
```

But, when I execute this, I have an error :

```
Unable to open W:\IGN\BDPARCELLAIRE-RGF93-LB93-MAJ2013-V4\BDPV_1-2_SHP_LAMB93_D01\COMMUNE.shp or W:\IGN\BDPARCELLAIRE-RGF93-LB93-MAJ2013-V4\BDPV_1-2_SHP_LAMB93_D01\COMMUNE.SHP.
W:\IGN\BDPARCELLAIRE-RGF93-LB93-MAJ2013-V4\BDPV_1-2_SHP_LAMB93_D01\COMMUNE.shp: dbf file (.dbf) can not be opened.
```

I really don't understand, because I tried to import the same layer using the graphical interface PostGIS and it works.

Where am I wrong in my code?

---

The dbf file is present.

Comment: is the .dbf file present?

Comment: What happens if you open your shape file in QGIS or other desktop GIS? Can you open the attribute table?